# remove special html tag from a string

Tags: java, string, tags, html

How can I remove special html tag from a string? Here is the string

> String testString ="It's the club that is discussing this with
>   the player's agent, but no decision has been taken," said Ancelotti,
>   who briefly coached Beckham during a loan spell at AC Milan.
>   divv class="og_rss_groups">

I have to remove `divv class="og_rss_groups"></divv` from the above string. How it is possible?

Comment: If you are looking for parsing HTML using Java try this : http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you put in code, you might want to post actually compiling code. Additionally, in the above code, there is no HTML tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String testString ="It's the club that is discussing this with the player's agent, but no decision has been taken," said Ancelotti, who briefly coached Beckham during a loan spell at AC Milan.
divv class=\"og_rss_groups\">";
String result = testString.replaceAll("whattoreplace","");

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTMLEntities](http://java.net/projects/htmlentities/). It will replace your quotes with HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try substring function of String class ?. You should also check why the un-desired string is coming at the first place.